# pathlib use glob to find all files with given stem

Tags: python, pathlib

Basically I have a working solution but given the simplicity of `pathlib` I feel like I am doing it wrong.

MWE:

```
filename = Path('a/b/c.txt')
# I want to find all files in `a/b` called `c` with any extension, e.g: `c.pdf`

list(filename.parent.glob(f"{filename.stem}.*"))
# [PosixPath('a/b/c.txt'), PosixPath('a/b/c.pdf')]
```

From a pathlib point of view I would have done something like `filename.glob("*")` but it does not work (returns `[]`).

I have found the `with_suffix` method in the documentation, but it is for replacement, not global finding.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `Path.glob("*")` and a list comprehension. It will feel more pythonic.

```py
filename = Path("a/b/c.txt")

[f for f in filename.parent.glob("*") if f.stem == filename.stem]
# [PosixPath('a/b/c.txt'), PosixPath('a/b/c.pdf')]
```

Also, you could use `Path.iterdir()` if you're only looking in a single directory.

```py
filename = Path("a/b/c.txt")

[f for f in filename.parent.iterdir() if f.stem == filename.stem]
# [PosixPath('a/b/c.txt'), PosixPath('a/b/c.pdf')]
```